# Highlighting the element after scrolling to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the fiddle I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/fz5Yk/5/

As you can see, it has a one-page scrolling navigation. I want to achieve a highlighting effect (preferably using .animate function) to the headings in `<strong> </strong>` tags when scrolling to a section. Just scroll the page manually and you will see a highlighting in the navigation menu; item of the scrolled section, but I can't quite resolve the js codes in order to apply the same to the headings, and an intervention in it with .animate function seems much more difficult to me. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin-page seems well-documented; https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav.

Just put an animation on the location you scroll to inside the `end:` definition;

```
$('#nav').onePageNav({
    end: function() {
        //I get fired when the animation is ending
    }
});
```

**Test update**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var visible_start = window.pageYOffset;
    var window_height = window.innerHeight;
    var section3_height = $('#section-3').height();
    var section3_start = $('#section-3')[0].offsetTop;

    if ((visible_start - window_height >= section3_start) &&
       $('#section-3').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

Comment: OK, that's smart. But just one thing, this only happens when the scrolling happens via clicking an item, not when manually scrolling as I explained above. When you scroll manually, the item in the menu is highlighted/get selected (background color changes) as if it was clicked, and  I want the animation happens when I'm at a specific section, only through scrolling to it.

Comment: try `scrollChange: function($currentListItem) { /*I get fired when you enter a section and I pass the list item of the section*/ }` ? Docs here: https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

Comment: Well, what am I doing wrong? I'm just trying to highlight the heading in the section 3, just when I'm at #section-3. :(

Comment: Try something like in my update. Can't show it on jsFiddle, as it will not match the window measurements correctly. That should get you started by finding out when your user is going over your section-3.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and generosity but this did not work. Well, isn't there any other way out to achieve this? I thought it was easier to make this happen. What a torture!